# How to format a line in current cursor to <h1> or <p> tag by javascript execCommand?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm learning to format editable html text and display in UIWebView

//html file

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//Load to WebView

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:
                    [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]] readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

                     baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]]
 ];
```

Some tag like **b** or **i** can insert or removed to current select text by

```
-(IBAction)bold:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('bold')"];
}

-(IBAction)italic:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('italic')"];
}
```

### I'd like to find a command to format current line text into **h1**, **h2** ....**p** or **pre** tag.

I search a lot but still stuck. Please give a suggestion!

Comment: interesting question, but must use `execCommand` ?

Comment: Thanks! I need to format it from a button in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my answer from [this document](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html)

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p')"];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'h1')"];
```